# How do I store developer "selvesets" I dont want to push to origin across developers

Tags: git, team-foundation-server

We just switched from TFSC to GIT, and there are some issues finding a good alternative to shelvesets

The use case:
As a developer we often want to change certain settings, so that our test environment targets a different host, before we did this with shelvesets

"Target servertype1 AcceptTest"

"Target servertype1 Debug"

"Target servertype1 production"

"Target servertype2 AcceptTest"

"Target servertype2 Debug"

"Target servertype2 production"

(All these change a lot of connectionstrings)

So if I had to test some data against servertype1 and servertype2 in Accepttest I would pull down those 2 shelvesets, but I would never checkin/commit them.

In git we have tried having these as branches, but then when you switch to this "target servertype"-branch, do you code, then when I want to push I do not want to change the connectionstrings on Origin.

Also if I want to use a combination of changes, it gives issues, do we then need to branch into a third branch thats a combination of x other branches

We have tried stashing, but thats not shared across developers, and we dont want to manage these connection settings on each different developer PC

Any tips on how to solve this issue or a different way to go about it

Comment: Have the configuration files in a configuration directory and the dev just copies the one he needs for his stuff?

Comment: Not good if you need to change 20 files into different directories, would take a long time to manually copypaste them in, and is very error prone

Comment: Did you consider setting up a script to do this? Another alternative could be to use a second GIT for the configuration or maybe a GIT sub-module. I've never used sub-modules so I'm not sure if they would offer a solution for this.